# Left adjoint of diagonal functor

Tags: category-theory

How would i go about showing that the diagonal functor ∆ : **Mon** → **Mon** × **Mon** has a left adjoint?

Comment: Well, you would start by writing down the definition of what it means for a functor to be such a left adjoint. How is that step going?

Comment: Yeah i have the definitions in front of me, im just can't work out what type of structure FX should be.

Comment: Well, it should be a monoid...What property should it have? Incidentally it would be much more natural to write $FX$ as $F(X,Y)$, if $F$ is to denote your desired left adjoint.

Comment: Would it be similar to U : Mon → Set? where order and amount of times matter, so a list?

Comment: Disregard my earlier comment; I'd momentarily forgotten what this functor looked like in categories like $\mathbf{Mon}$, and your analogy isn't so far off. Can you see why this adjoint gives you binary coproducts in $\mathbf{Mon}$? If you know what the coproducts are in this category, that's all you need.

Comment: I imagine its like a list but each element of the list is made up of 2 tuple, [(x1,y1),(x2,y2)...] and the operation is pointwise concatenation? Not sure if im using the right words.

Comment: @5Six that sounds like the idea. Elements are in essence strings $x_1y_1x_2...$ and the operation is concatenation, together with the operations of $X$ and $Y$ when elements of one monoid or the other end up next to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you want to see is that such a left adjoint gives you *binary coproducts*. Let's denote the object to which the left adjoint takes $\langle A,B\rangle$ by $A\square B$. Then left adjointness tells us that there is a natural correspondence $$\dfrac{A\square B\longrightarrow C}{\langle A,B\rangle\longrightarrow\Delta(C)}.$$ That is, a morphism $f:A\square B\to C$ corresponds to a unique pair of arrows $f_1:A\to C$ and $f_2:B\to C$; which is just what a coproduct of $A,B$ is.

How the coproduct is actually constructed is a little more complicated. The easiest construction for $A+B$ is indeed as a set of strings (or rather, equivalence classes of strings), but not quite as you've suggested. What you use is strings of elements from $A\cup B$, quotiented by an equivalence relation that respects all the equalities in $A$ and $B$ (the details are hairy, but what you're looking for is a *free product* of monoids).

Comment: Anyone actually know what the 2 homomorphism from A → F(A, B), B → F(A, B) is, and also the construction of F(A, B)?

Comment: @5Six - The injection $A\to F(A,B)$ takes $a\in A$ to the equivalence class of the length one string $a$ in $F(A,B)$, similarly with $B\to F(A,B)$. Again, search for the term "free product" for the exact construction of $F(A,B)$ it's essentially the same thing as the free product of groups. I'm not going to write out the whole definition here when a Google search can turn it up.

Comment: K thanks a lot, yeah i did some reading on free product on groups and thought it might be similar but different to monoids, but couldnt find anything on monoids.

Comment: I *think* have a book that has the details for $\mathbf{Mon}$, but I'll need to double check in the morning. I'll update this with a reference if I'm remembering correctly.

Comment: Any name of the book off the top of your head? work deadline soon lol

Comment: The one I'm thinking of is Awodey's *Category Theory*. I can't swear that it's in there, but he uses monoids as an example often enough that there's a good chance.

Comment: Is it the construction at the bottom of this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999454/in-the-coproduct-of-monoids-a-amalg-b-suppose-two-words-have-the-same-suffix

Comment: @5Six - Yes, the answer describes the appropriate construction.

Comment: @5Six On your course. I'm using the construction described for free products of groups here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product, since a group is just a monoid with an inverse

Comment: Really appreciate the help tyty. @DanielCastle u mean ur also doing the coursework?

Comment: @5Six Yup, since 4am. Typing it up in LaTeX is a pain.

Comment: Im just gonna take a picture of my paper, too much effort for all that.

Comment: @DanielCastle you got a discord i can add u on to check some of my stuff?